# Setting up monero blockchain explorer on unbuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, monerod-commands, ubuntu

I am trying to setup Monero blockchain explorer on Ubuntu 16.04 by following this [github repo](https://github.com/moneroexamples/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer).

I have checkout monero v0.12.1.0

but I am facing this error while running `make` command

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libgtest.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   tests/unit_tests/CMakeFiles/unit_tests.dir/build.make:1206: recipe for target 'tests/unit_tests/unit_tests' failed
>   make[3]: *** [tests/unit_tests/unit_tests] Error 1
>   make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/monero/build/release'
>   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4425: recipe for target 'tests/unit_tests/CMakeFiles/unit_tests.dir/all' failed
>   make[2]:**  [tests/unit_tests/CMakeFiles/unit_tests.dir/all] Error 2
>   make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/monero/build/release'
>   Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
>   make[1](https://github.com/moneroexamples/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer):  **[all] Error 2
>   make[1](https://github.com/moneroexamples/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer): Leaving directory '/home/monero/build/release'
>   Makefile:64: recipe for target 'release-all' failed
>   make: *** [release-all] Error 2

I couldn't find any solution yet? can anyone help?

Comment: Did you follow this part on the README? https://github.com/moneroexamples/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer#compile-and-run-the-explorer

Comment: @dEBRUYNE yes I followed this part, right now I am trying to re-setup, checked out the monero now running make command. may be I missed something

Comment: @dEBRUYNE can you please check the question, make command is throwing error.

Comment: Please see glv's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error `` "/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC" `` tells you that the *libgtest.a* file of your system has not been compiled with position independent code, which is necessary to compile *monerod*.

You must either compile *gtest* with the `-fPIC` flag on your system or uninstall the *gtest* version on your system for the version of *gtest* embedded in the monero source code to be used.

The second solution is probably easier:

```
apt-get remove libgtest-dev
cd directory_of_the_monero_sources
make clean
make
```